# InnoDB Failure of some kind

Tags: linux, mysql, database, innodb, database-administration

I have MySQL 5.5 installed. I tried to install Joolma but it failed. I went into their sql and replace EGNINE=InnoDB with MyISAM and the install worked.

InnoDB is listed under SHOW ENGINES;

Any idea what the cause is or how to fix this so other InnoDB sites can be used?

I had these errors:

```
MySQL ERROR No: 1030
MysqL Error: Got error -1 from storage engine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your my.cnf, locate `innodb_force_recovery` and change

`innodb_force_recovery = 4`

to

`innodb_force_recovery = 3`

Also ensure you have enough disk space for the database.

Comment: Yes, I have that. It is set to 6 atm.